# Прерывание работы скрипта при использовании SimpleXML

Tags: php, nginx

На ВПС установлен сервер NGINX+php-fpm.
Есть скрипт парсинга каталога:

```
  $html_kod = file_get_contents('catalog.xml');
  echo memory_get_usage(); //на nginx 5 695 376, на локалхост - показало 33 933 848 

  $catalog = new SimpleXMLElement($html_kod);
  echo memory_get_usage(); //на локалхост - 130 443 864 

  unset($html_kod);
  echo memory_get_usage(); //на локалхост - 33 934 088
....
```

При выполнении `$catalog = new SimpleXMLElement($html_kod);` на сервере при обработке больших файлов скрипт прерывается.

Когда каталог был 70МБ, работало нормально. Сейчас каталог весит 90Мб и на сервере скрипт не работает. На локалхост при этом работает нормально.
В веб-интерфейсе на сервере выдаёт ошибку:

> 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.4.6

Грешил на нехватку памяти и установил `memory_limit = 350M`, `max_execution_time = 7200`, `max_input_time = 7200` - не помогло... После запуска на локалхосте увидел, что памяти вроде нужно только 130Мб. В логах тоже ничего вроде не нашёл (возможно не те смотрел)...

Подскажите, как можно определить, почему прерывается скрипт? Какие настройки еще нужно изменить?

```
---------------------------------------
```

Установил `memory_limit = 500M` - заработало, но это половина памяти всего ВПС. Подскажите, как можно измерить сколько берет `SimpleXMLElement` под себя? 
Подскажите, возможно есть другие менее ресурсоемкие библиотеки для парсинга XML?

Comment: в логи надо смотреть - nginx и php-fpm

Comment: Возможно по таймауту падает скрипт. Установите `ignore_user_abort(1);` //Игнорировать обрыв связи с браузером и  задайте неограниченное время работы скрипта `set_time_limit(0);`

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick не помогло. Вообще время ожидания я установил 10мин, а 502 Bad Gateway где-то сек через 5-10 вылетает

Comment: Так с этого и надо начинать, что скрипт работает долго в реальности. У php своя настройка time_limit, у nginx'а свои настройки ожидания бекенда, у php-fpm и у того свои отдельные настройки есть.

Comment: @Мелкий время увеличено и в настройках nginx и в настройках php-fpm. Реально скрипт должен работать несколько минут и при каталогах около 70МБ всё работало великолепно...
Сейчас скрипт прерывается на строке $catalog = new SimpleXMLElement($html_kod); а это почти начало работы скрипта...

Comment: В логах-то что? И сколько памяти всего? memory_get_usage не умеет показывать реальную память на процесс, только затраченную самим php кодом. Например, используемая в simplexml libxml может неплохо отожрать памяти в себя. И вообще не надо большие таски вызывать из веба. Запускайте в консоли.

Comment: установил memory_limit = 500M - заработало, но это половина памяти всего ВПС.... как можно измерить сколько берет под себя SimpleXMLElement

Comment: а что вы хотите от DOM-парсера? конечно, он будет много памяти есть. Хотите быстро и с малыми ресурсами парсить xml - используйте SAX-парсеры.